# ASP.NET JavaScript function undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've tried debugging the following error for several hours with no solution (I want to break the keyboard in half). Please help. I need it.

> Unhandled exception at line 90, column 95 in
>   http://localhost:51770/SimpleAjax.aspx
>
> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'callAjaxMethod' is undefined

This method is being called from a button on a page:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" Text="Calculate" OnClientClick="callAjaxMethod()"/>
```

**The JS:**

```
function callAjaxMethod()
{

   // e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SimpleAjax.asmx/IsLeapYear",
        data: '{year: "' + $("#<%=txtYear.ClientID%>").val() + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.d) {
                $('#<%=txtResult.ClientID%>').val('Leap Year');
            }
            else {
                $('#<%=txtResult.ClientID%>').val('Not a Leap Year');
            }
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            $('#<%=txtResult.ClientID%>').val("Error in calling Ajax:" + response.d);
        }
    });
}
```

**Code from the ASMX file:**

```
    /// Summary description for SimpleAjax
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://automatedpumpcontroller.somee.com/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class SimpleAjax : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]

        public static bool IsLeapYear(int year)
        {
            return DateTime.IsLeapYear(year);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other Javascript code inside the `script` block? Sometimes, a function is undefined because of a problem in another part of the client code.

Comment: How do I check that in VS 2015?

Comment: If `callAjaxMethod` is inside a `script` block, is there any other code inside the same block?

Comment: It's in a JavaScript file all by itself. I copied it in its entirety.

Comment: OK. How do you include that Javascript file in your markup? Can you show that line in the question?

Comment: It is referenced by the button click as shown above if that's what you mean.

Comment: Two things you must check in your code. One is Any post back happening in your page ? Another one is your js file reference is properly placed in correct page!!

Comment: Added the reference to the master which works. However get this error now Unhandled exception at line 1864, column 2 in http://localhost:51770/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%=txtYear.ClientID%>

Answer (score 0):

If your function callAjaxMethod is in separate js file then you need to include that file on your page like below

e.g. Js file with name is kept on js\app.js and your page is SimpleAjax.aspx

then on SimpleAjax.aspx
you need to add script tag in head

```
<script src="js\app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Got this working by adding the script to the master page head. However now get this error. Unhandled exception at line 1864, column 2 in http://localhost:51770/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%=txtYear.ClientID%>

Comment: yes it should be because you cannot use the asp server tag in js file <%= %>, it can be used on aspx page itself. For that you have to include your function on your aspx page itself or you need to replace the selector that are using the server tag with jquery selector like this **$("[id$='txtYear']")**

Answer (score 0):

I think your Issue is with reference of JS. Did you include JS ?

```js
function callAjaxMethod() {
  alert('in');
}
```

```html
  
<input type="button" id="btn" onclick="callAjaxMethod();" />
```

Comment: Added the reference in the master. Now get this error: Unhandled exception at line 1864, column 2 in http://localhost:51770/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%=txtYear.ClientID%>

Comment: $("#<%=txtYear.ClientID%>").val() what your are getting here ?

Comment: The year which is in a text box